# Querying parse in unity project returns all blank data

Tags: c#, arrays, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I am implementing the Parse Unity SDK in order to have a high score system. I run a query on my data to get the top ten players and their scores. (It should be sorted by score). For some reason when my code is run, I get a blank string for the name and a 0 for the score even though my data has real values in it.

Here is the query:

```
    int[] scores = new int[10];
    string[] names = new string[10];
    int i = 0;
    var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("HighScores").OrderByDescending ("score").Limit (10);
    query.FindAsync().ContinueWith (t =>
    {
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;
        foreach (var obj in results)
        {
            scores[i] = obj.Get<int>("score");
            names[i] = obj.Get<string>("playerName");
            i++;
        }
    });
```

The class name is "HighScores" and I am trying to access the score ("score") and player name ("playerName") of each saved entry.

EDIT:

I found that there are zero results returned so it must be something with the query. I don't see what could be wrong with it.

**8/17/15**
I still have not found out what is going on with my query. Any ideas?

Comment: did you get total of 10 entries in result?

Comment: @Umairm Yes I did but that doesn't mean anything since the size of the arrays are 10 and I'm limiting my query to a count of 10 right?

Comment: It does not depend on size of your array. as you are limiting it to 10 you should get at most 10 values in result so are you getting `result.Count == 10` or not?

Comment: @UmairM If i keep a count in the foreach, I get that there are 0 objects in results. (I can't do result.Count). I have no idea what is wrong with the query.

Comment: @UmairM  Do you see something wrong with the query? The syntax seems fine. HighScores is the class, score is the players score and playerName is the name of the player corresponding with the score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was getting the data from the query. The query was fine all along. The actual issue was that I was trying to output my newly found scores to a string that was being called before the query was finished getting the data since the query is an asynchronous call. Instead of doing it this way, I let the query run fully and once the query is finished, I set a static bool called finishedRunningQuery to true. Now in the update() method I have it check: if (finishedRunningQuery) then update the high score text. This fixes the issue.